# How to get a fully qualified path to MS Explorer in .NET?

Tags: .net, file, operating-system, explorer

How to get a fully qualified path to MS Explorer in .NET?

The path will be used to launch a new instance of MS Explorer with some command line parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Explorer is always in the Path, so just calling explorer.exe with the command line parameters should be enough.

Same applies to Internet Explorer, whose file name is iexplore.exe.

Answer (score 0):

As said by @devio, you don't really need to specify it as it's in the path, but for the sake of completeness, you could use the `Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables` method:

```
string path = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"%SystemRoot%\Explorer.exe");
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks!

The full code snippet for anyone interested, is:

```
    // Launch MS Explorer with the correct log file selected.

    //string pathToExplorer = System.IO.Path.Combine( Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%WinDir%"),
    //                                                "explorer.exe");

    string pathToExplorer = "explorer.exe";

    string pathToLogFile = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName + ".log";

    string arguments = String.Format(   CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                        "/select, \"{0}\"",
                                        pathToLogFile);

    // C:\Windows\explorer.exe /select, "C:\projects\trunk\bin\MyCompany.App.StackTester.exe.log"

    Process.Start(  pathToExplorer,
                    arguments);
```